# Infinite-precision arithmetic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, precision

In JavaScript, the function `alert((3*3*Math.sqrt(2))/13)` prints `0.9790709277967582`, which is only an approximation of the expression's true value. Is there any way to perform arithmetic operations in JavaScript like this one without loss of precision, so that something like `3*3*sqrt(2))/13` would output `9*(2)^(1/2)/13`, which is the exact value, instead of `0.9790709277967582`, which is only an approximation?

Comment: There might be a general-purpose algebra library in JavaScript for this purpose, but I haven't found any libraries like that yet. In theory, it would certainly be possible to implement such a library (if a library doesn't already exist for this purpose.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good open source JavaScript math library for floating point operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287744/good-open-source-javascript-math-library-for-floating-point-operations)

Comment: @AndyRay Are any of these libraries able to represent numbers (such as `sqrt(2)/13`) as fractions, instead of representing them as decimal approximations with limited precision? Some precision would inevitably be lost if all of these libraries represented the numbers as decimals with a fixed number of digits.

Comment: Fortunately, there is a JavaScript library for manipulating fractions: http://hypervolu.me/~erik/fraction.js/

Answer (score 2):

There's a library for this here: https://github.com/whatgoodisaroad/Big-js/downloads

It has a bunch of functions like `myNum.add(otherNum)`, so it might be a little harder to use. However, if you need infinite precision it will have to do.

Example:

```
var number1 = new Big("12.00000000000000005");
var number2 = new Big("12");

number1.lessThanOrEqualTo(number2); // False, like it should be.
```

Comment: Is there a function in this library for printing a number as a string? (i. e., so that var number3 = new Big("sqrt(2)/5") would print `sqrt(2)/5`, instead of an approximation of this number)?

Comment: @AndersonGreen No, I don't think there is any library that will do that. How about just printing `sqrt(2)/5`? Why can't you do that?

Comment: Then I still wouldn't be able to print the output of an expression as a fraction. :/

Comment: So this works for decimals; does it work for large numbers greater than the "safe limit" (`2^53-1`)?